# how to sort a csv file using variables

Tags: python, csv

I'm trying to sort a csv file by each student's highest score (of the three they got). Here is my code.

```
def score_high(filename):

    people = []
    list11 =[]
    count = 0

    with open(filename) as Class:
        reader = c.reader(Class,delimiter=",")
        for row in reader:
            people = []
            people.append(row[0])

            if int(row[1]) > int(row[2]) and int(row[1]) > int(row[3]):
                score = row[1]

            elif int(row[2]) > int(row[3]):
                score = row[2]
            elif int(row[3]) > int(row[2]):
                score = row[3]
            people.append(score)

            count = count+1
            list11.insert(count,people)

    sort=sorted(list11, key = o.itemgetter('''a sort for the score'''), reverse = False)
    for eachline in sort:
        print( eachline)
```

csv file:

```
kieran,3,10,7
ben,4,8,5
ethan,9,1,4
oliver,7,2,3
```

Comment: *"is there any way to do this"* - yes

Comment: please may you tell me

Comment: No. This isn't a code-writing service, you should do your homework yourself.

Comment: ive look everywhere and keep getting errors and cant seem to sort it by there highest score

Comment: Then include a [mcve] of your current code and a detailed description of the problem with it, not just a code dump and a whine. See [ask].

Comment: ok thanks jonrsharpe

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Would it be possible for you to provide the specific errors that you are getting? Please do take a look at [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and do introduce the problem first before you post your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of problems here. First off, using `'''a sort for the score'''` as an index for `itemgetter` is so completely wrong. You're supposed to pass `itemgetter` the index of the list (or tuple) item that you would like it to get - in this case that value is `1`.

Secondly, you're not getting out the correct ordering because the `sort` function is trying to sort on string values, and if you try to compare `'10' > '9'` you'll see that the output is actually `False`. You need to cast the scores as integers before you append them.

A final note - I wouldn't `import csv as c` or `import operator as o`. You should be able to type out three or eight letters, and it makes the code significantly harder to read. Remember, code is read far more often than it is written.

```
import csv
import operator

def score_high(filename):

    people = []
    list11 =[]
    count = 0

    with open(filename) as Class:
        reader = csv.reader(Class,delimiter=",")
        for row in reader:
            people = []
            people.append(row[0])

            if int(row[1]) > int(row[2]) and int(row[1]) > int(row[3]):
                score = row[1]

            elif int(row[2]) > int(row[3]):
                score = row[2]
            elif int(row[3]) > int(row[2]):
                score = row[3]
            people.append(int(score))

            count = count+1
            list11.append(people) # use append here, you're going to sort it anyways

    sort = sorted(list11, key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
    for s in sort:
        print(s)
    return sort
```

You also never check for the case where the highest score is a duplicate within a student's list, but I'll leave that for you to do on your own.

Comment: thanks is there any way to print them on a separate line

Comment: `for s in sort: print(s)`

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv
import operator

marks = operator.itemgetter(1,2,3)
with open('path/to/file') as infile:
    data = list(csv.reader(infile))
data.sort(key=lambda row: max(int(i) for i in marks(row)))

for row in data: print(row)
```